# compiling serverside coffeescript with gulp

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, gulp

I am unsure on how to compile coffescript on the serverside. When compiling it on the client, you just throw the resulting javascript files into a temporary file and include it the index html page

But I can't see how this is doable on the serverside?

Comment: What's the point of compiling server-side coffeescript? You can run and `require` `.coffee` files directly without manual compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to compile your `.coffee` files in order to use them in your project.

You can run `.coffee` files directly by installing [`coffee-script` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coffee-script) globally

```
npm install -g coffee-script
```

and then using its `coffee` utility instead of `node` binary

```
coffee my_app.coffee
```

If, for some reason, you don't want to install global packages, you may add `coffee-script` to your `package.json` and run your project with it:

```
./node_modules/.bin/coffee my_app.coffee
```

In this case you'll probably want to add this code to the `scripts` section of your `package.json`, so you'll be able to run your project simply by typing `npm start`.

If your goal is to `require` some `.coffee` files into your JS project (or from your `gulpfile.js`), you should add `coffee-script` to your `package.json` and then register CoffeeScript compiler for `node.js` by adding the following line to your `.js` file:

```
require('iced-coffee-script/register');
```

The only case when you'll actually need to compile your `.coffee` files is when you're writing an npm package.